# PHP: Issue looping through an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array called `test_array`:

```
[0]=>
  object(stdClass)#6745 (2) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(12) "768682798201"
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(33) "13.5" Test/Viper Red"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#5843 (2) {
    ["meta_value"]=>
    string(12) "768682798218"
    ["post_title"]=>
    string(33) "15.5" Test/Viper Red"
  }
```

The problem I have is with looping through this array using a `foreach`, I'm attempting to loop through the array and echo a nicely formatted string for each object element. The result should be like:

> 768682798218 | 15.5" Test/Viper Red

My code is as follows but this does not currently work, could anyone suggest what the issue is here?:

```
  foreach ($test_array as $test) {
   echo $test->meta_value . ' | ' . $test->post_title;
}
```

Comment: What does it mean "not working"? Do you get any errors? Add [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) at the top of your file(s): `ini_set("display_errors", 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: What output you got ?

Comment: Problem here with the quotation marks string(33) "13.5" Test/Viper Red", also post the error you get.

Comment: @NessRosales: what problem with quotes? That's a perfectly valid `var_dump()` output...

Comment: I just realized they are escaped, my bad. @MarcB

Comment: I cannot see anything that should be wrong with the above.  Though, if you have stdClasses with more fields than the above, or not know for sure what names the fields have, you could use `echo implode(' | ',(array)$test);`  in the loop instead.